# How to call a native view method from JavaScript

Tags: react-native

I have an Android class that extends `SimpleViewManager` class and encapsulates a `MapView`. Setting props from React Native JavaScript class works like a charm (using the `@ReactProp` annotation). However, i'd like to be able to call a method on the view, something like the following:

```
public void centerToMyLocation(MapView view) {
    view.getController().setCenter(myLocation);
}
```

I've tried using the `@ReactMethod` annotation, getting a ref for the `MapView` in JavaScript and then call the `centerToMyLocation` method on that object. But it doesn't work (I get `mapViewRef.centerToMyLocation is not a function` error).

How can I call the method from a JavaScript class where I render the native `MapView` component?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, the following worked for me:

1. Add a `ref` to the native component in the `render` method of the JavaScript class.
2. Use `findNodeHandle` method from `react-native` package, passing the obtained `ref` as an argument. The `findNodeHandle` method returns a react ID, save it.
3. Use `UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand` method from `react-native`, passing the react ID as the first argument. Second argument is a command id. Third argument are additional arguments (can be `null`).
4. Override `receiveCommand` method in your `ViewManager` native class, which exposes the component. In this method, handle the command.

Example JS:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.mapViewHandle = findNodeHandle(this.mapViewRef);
}

center() {
    UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(this.mapViewHandle, 0, null);
}

render() {
    return (
        <MapView
            ref={(mv) => this.mapViewRef = mv} />
    );
}
```

Example Java:

```
@Override
public void receiveCommand(MapView view, int commandId, @Nullable ReadableArray args) {
    super.receiveCommand(view, commandId, args);
    if (commandId == 0) {
        if (mMyLocation != null) {
            view.getController().setCenter(mMyLocation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The missing piece was `findNodeHandle` for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it:

You just have to create a sibling **UI Native Module** to accompany the **UI Native Component** as seen in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48652677/1658268)

That should be an easier and more future proof way to do it.